# AttributeError: module 'djangoschool' has no attribute 'wsgi'

Tags: python, django, web, iis, wsgi

I once finished deploy it on another server without this error, but I try this with new server and install my new window server 2019.I start do it again but it got an error.

I deploy my django project on IIS.I follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpFU16KrJcQ
When I browse my website on localhost.
It got error messages like this.

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 603, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = getattr(handler, name)
AttributeError: module 'djangoschool' has no attribute 'wsgi'


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Location: C:\intepub2\wwwroot

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI" 
      path="*" 
      verb="*" 
      modules="FastCgiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="c:\python37\python.exe|c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
      resourceType="Unspecified" 
      requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub2\wwwroot\djangoschool" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="djangoschool.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="djangoschool.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Location: C:\intepub2\wwwroot\djangoschool\djangoschool

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for djangoschool project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y!6o7s+hwc=5_n(((=be3#ktnqycq@2^0bez!$6!p8baep_^o7'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'school',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'import_export'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoschool.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'school/template')],
        #'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,'school/template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoschool.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home-page'
```

Location: C:\intepub2\wwwroot\djangoschool\djangoschool

wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for djangoschool project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoschool.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods to solve the problem:

1. It may cause by the extra directory djangoschool, remove it and try again.
2. Check your Project-Folder, you will find a __ init__.py file, remove it and try again.